# Adding attachment to Google Calendar with Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a Google document from my Google drive to a calendar event in a calendar I own. The frustrating thing is that I had it and while playing with the code lost it! The code I have below will add a calendar event, but no attachment appears and no error arises when the code is run. If anyone has a simple example of attaching a file to a calendar event, it would be much appreciate.

```
   function createEvent() {
    var calendarId = 'primary';
    var start = getRelativeDate(1, 12);
    var end = getRelativeDate(1, 13);
    var event = {
        summary: 'Lunch Meeting',
        location: 'The Deli',
        description: 'To discuss our plans for the presentation next week.',
        start: {
            dateTime: start.toISOString()
        },
        end: {
            dateTime: end.toISOString()
        },
        attendees: [{
            email: 'alice@example.com'
        }, {
            email: 'bob@example.com'
        }],

        attachments: [{
                fileId: "1sGm4o0DVJFjJQun_oj1PWD9MuFCiikqamM7B0TkwH6w",
            },
        ],
        colorId: 9
    };

    event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
    Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}


function getRelativeDate(daysOffset, hour) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysOffset);
    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    date.setMilliseconds(0);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Does the following answer help: [Attachment on Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34867068/2946873)

Comment: I've actually tried that piece of code and it hangs on this line:
var resp = Calendar.Events.insert(eventObj, calendarId, {'supportsAttachments': true});

The error message says 'Not FOUND'(line 265 file'CODE"). I have activated advanced services for the Calendar API. I seem to be hanging up on how to set the supportsAttachments to true from within the Google scripts editor.

Answer (score 0):

For attaching Drive files in an Event, you can check out the [Add Drive attachments to events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events).

Basically you'll first need to `file.get()` from Drive and use the `alternateLink`, `title`, and `mimeType` properties. The second step is to update the event by setting the `supportsAttachments` to `true`.

Once done, you can use `events.insert` or `events.patch` and `setAttachments` to the event. The final step would be to call `execute` to finalize the call.

Comment: Normally I am of average intelligence, but when I look at their examples I end up like a deer in the headlights. Does anyone have a simple code example to add an attachment to a calendar event from within the Google script editor? I think my confusion arises when it is written to be run within JavaScript or Python as the above example does. I will work with your suggestion, but a simple Google script would certainly ease my troubled mind. 

Comment: Wouldn't the Python sample in the documentation be sufficient enough? Or is it that you want a sample specific to app scripts?

Comment: I've never used python, in fact never used javascript or Google scripts until a year ago. My problem would be not knowing where a problem is coming from if I try to adapt python to Google scripts. I am assuming I can't just cut and paste the code to GS and then add my specific parameters to make it work. If that is possible, then let me know and I'll work at it.
As I said in the original post, I had the blasted thing working perfectly at one time, but somehow lost it.
A simple Google script would be much appreciated in order to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm working my way through, but I am stuck on how to set supportsAttachments to true from within Google scripts. Any suggestions?