# Create an event with an attachment on Calendar via Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I couldn't find a way to add an attachment to my calendar event. I hope there should be a simple way like below snippet,

```
function createNewEvent()
{
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1eqaThzYmTbZzP-my file id-rXrBrWDW8DwMNeU');   //get file to be attached
 var title  = 'Apollo 11 Landing';
 var startTime = new Date('January 20, 2016 20:00:00 UTC');
 var endTime = new Date('January 20, 2016 21:00:00 UTC');
 var options = {description:'Sample description', location: 'The Moon', attachments:file}; //can we add attachments like this?

 var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. First you must [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar). Then you can do something like this:

```
function createNewEvent() {
  var calendarId = ''; //Calendar Id String
  var fileId = ''; // File Id String
  var start = new Date('January 20, 2016 20:00:00 UTC');
  var end = new Date('January 20, 2016 21:00:00 UTC');
  var eventObj = {
    summary: 'Apollo 11 Landing',
    location: 'The Moon',
    description: 'Sample description',
    start: {dateTime: start.toISOString()},
    end: {dateTime: end.toISOString()},
    attachments: [{
        'fileUrl': 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + fileId,
        'title': 'Moon Docs'
    }]
  };
  var resp = Calendar.Events.insert(eventObj, calendarId, {'supportsAttachments': true});
  Logger.log(resp); // Check out the response in the logs!
}
```

For more options, check out the [Events documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).

Comment: So we need to use Advanced Calendar Services,This is perfect! 
found my calendar Id like [this.](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/203645966-Find-your-Google-Calendar-ID-for-the-Events-block)