# How can I attach multiple files from Google Form to a Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-drive-api

I've built a Google Form that I'm using to create calendar events, and the only thing I haven't worked out yet is how to properly get any attached Drive files from the Form onto the calendar.

I found a very useful snippet of code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853043/create-an-event-with-an-attachment-on-calendar-via-google-apps-script)
that has shown me how to attach a file to my calendar event using its Drive `fileId`, but only from a standalone script where the file info is put in manually. 
Where I'm getting stuck, is that I'm receiving an array of file ID's from my form, and I want to attach them to my calendar event with their actual, respective file names. I know I'll have to iterate through the array somehow, but I especially can't seem to pull the file name info from each of the files.

I am not a programmer by trade, so I'm learning as I go.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my app script code for my Google Form (The calendar is used for AV event setups and teardowns at a college).

Thanks in advance.
Joel

```
//Load the Moment.js library once.
//MFSDXCPBYb-JUlxKtMlncfZPjmlt5YPXB
var moment = Moment.load();


var formInput = (function() {
    return {
        formId: "xxxxx",
        calendarId: "xxxxx",
        formMap: {
            ticket: "Ticket Number",
            eventTitle: "Event Title",
            startTime : "Event Date and Start Time",
            duration: "Event Duration in Hours",
            description: "Event Description",
            location: "Event Location",
            setup: "Set Up Required?",
            eventDocs: "Event Docs"

        }
    }
})();

function onFormSubmit() {
    getFormResponse.formResponse();
    createEvent.newEvent();
}

var getFormResponse = (function() {
    // Get a form object by opening the form using the
    // form id stored in the formInput variable object
    return {
        formResponse: function() {
        var form = FormApp.openById(formInput.formId);
        //Get all responses from the form. 
        //This method returns an array of form responses
        responses = form.getResponses();
        //find the length of the responses array
        length = responses.length;
        //find the index of the most recent form response
        //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
        //is the total number of responses minus one
        lastResponse = responses[length-1];
        //get an array of responses to every question item 
        //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
        itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();
        //create an empty object to store data from the last 
        //form response
        //that will be used to create a calendar event
        eventObject = {};
            //Loop through each item response in the item response array
            for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
                //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
                var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
                    //get the submitted response to the form item being
                    //iterated on
                    thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
                //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
                //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
                //use the formInput variable formMap sub object to match 
                //form question titles to property keys in the event object
                switch (thisItem) {
                    case formInput.formMap.ticket:
                    eventObject.ticket = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(eventObject.ticket);
                    break;
                    case formInput.formMap.eventTitle:
                    eventObject.title = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break;
                    case formInput.formMap.startTime:
                    eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break;
                    case formInput.formMap.duration:
                    eventObject.duration = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break; 
                    case formInput.formMap.description:
                    eventObject.description = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break;
                    case formInput.formMap.location:
                    eventObject.location = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break;
                    case formInput.formMap.setup:
                    eventObject.setup = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break;
                    case formInput.formMap.eventDocs:
                    eventObject.eventDocs = thisResponse;
                    //Logger.log(thisResponse);
                    break;
                } 
            }
        return eventObject;
        }
    };
})();


var createEvent = (function() {   
    return {
        newEvent: function() {
            var eventStartTime = moment(eventObject.startTime);
            var eventEndTime = eventStartTime.clone().add(eventObject.duration, 'hours');
            var eventSetupStart = eventStartTime.clone().subtract(2, 'hours');
            var eventSetupEnd = eventSetupStart.clone().add(1, 'hour');
            var eventTeardownStart = eventEndTime.clone().add(30, 'minutes');
            var eventTeardownEnd = eventTeardownStart.clone().add(30, 'minutes');


            // create if else loop to test if setup is needed
            if (eventObject.setup === 'Yes') {

            // create base event with default calendar color label
            var event = {
            summary: eventObject.ticket + " | " + eventObject.title,
            start: {
                dateTime: eventStartTime.format()
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: eventEndTime.format()
            },
            location: eventObject.location,
            description: eventObject.description,
            attachments: [{
                  'fileUrl': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + eventObject.eventDocs
                }]
            };

            // create setup event with green label
            var setup = {
            summary: eventObject.ticket + " | " + "Set Up -",
            start: {
                dateTime: eventSetupStart.format()
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: eventSetupEnd.format()
            },
            location: eventObject.location,
            description: eventObject.description,
            colorId: 10
            };

            // create teardown event with green label
            var teardown = {
            summary: eventObject.ticket + " | " + "Tear Down -",
            start: {
                dateTime: eventTeardownStart.format()
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: eventTeardownEnd.format()
            },
            location: eventObject.location,
            description: "",
            colorId: 10
            };
            event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, formInput.calendarId, {
                'supportsAttachments': true
                });
            setup = Calendar.Events.insert(setup, formInput.calendarId);
            teardown = Calendar.Events.insert(teardown, formInput.calendarId);

            } else {
                // create monitoring-only event with grey label
                var eventMon = {
                summary: eventObject.ticket + " | " + eventObject.title,
                start: {
                    dateTime: eventStartTime.format()
                },
                end: {
                    dateTime: eventEndTime.format()
                },
                location: eventObject.location,
                description: eventObject.description,
                colorId: 8
                };
                eventMon = Calendar.Events.insert(eventMon, formInput.calendarId, {
                'supportsAttachments': true
                });  
            }
        }
    }
})();
```